# Convert dataframe from long to wide while retaining order of values (dtype datetime)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, python-datetime

I have a dataframe called `df` that looks similar to this (except the number of entries in the `Visit Date` column associated with each `Client ID` goes up to 74, and there are several hundred unique `Client IDs` - I have simplified it here).

```
Visit Date  Client ID
2016-05-25  C1009404
2016-06-30  C1009404
2016-07-14  C1009404
2016-07-20  C1009405
2016-08-03  C1009405
2016-08-08  C1009405
2016-08-10  C1009405
2016-08-15  C1009406
2016-08-17  C1009406
2016-08-24  C1009406
```

I want to convert it from long-to-wide, such that it looks like this:

```
Client ID  Visit_1     Visit_2     Visit_3     Visit_4
C1009404   2016-05-25  2016-06-30  2016-07-14
C1009405   2016-07-20  2016-08-03  2016-08-08  2016-08-10
C1009406   2016-08-15  2016-08-17  2016-08-24
```

I have tried the following code:

```
df_wide = df.groupby(['Client ID'], as_index=False).agg(lambda x: ', '.join(set(x.astype(str))))
df_wide = pd.concat([df_wide[['Client ID','ENROLLED_DT']], df_wide['VISIT_DT'].str.split(',', expand=True)], axis=1)
df_wide = df_wide.rename(columns={0: 'Visit_1', 1: 'Visit_2', 2: 'Visit_3', 3: 'Visit_4'})
```

It produces the desired result, but the dates are no longer in order. How do I do this but keep the dates in order, ascending from left to right?

Comment: Maybe ranking the values as per Client ID and then using pivot would do the trick. Give it a try

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may need create another key for helping the `pivot`

```
df.assign(key=df.groupby('ClientID').cumcount()+1).\
    pivot('ClientID','key','VisitDate').\
      fillna('').\
        add_prefix('Visit_')
Out[152]: 
key           Visit_1     Visit_2     Visit_3     Visit_4
ClientID                                                 
C10094042  2016-05-25  2016-06-30  2016-07-14            
C10094056  2016-07-20  2016-08-03  2016-08-08  2016-08-10
C10094061  2016-08-15  2016-08-17  2016-08-24
```